# Do you have to be the first to flag a post to receive a 'helpful flag' vote?

Tags: discussion, flags, flag-badges

When flagging a post, do you have to be the first user to flag a post in order for your flag to be counted as a 'helpful flag'?

For example, to receive the Deputy badge you must 'raise 80 helpful flags' and then reviewers approve of the flag, or if the moderator agrees with it, then it counts as 'helpful'.

Do you have to be the first user to raise a flag? Or can you be a follow-up flag and still receive a 'helpful flag' vote?

Comment: You don't have to be first to get your flag marked as helpful. (Example: When 4 people flag a post as spam and it gets removed, then all 4 people get their flag marked as helpful.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, the order in which flags were placed on a post doesn't really impact which are marked helpful or not. If four people flag a non-answer as "not an answer" and a moderator or reviewers delete that post, all flags are marked helpful.

Different types of flags may be handled differently, though. Something with spam and "not an answer" flags on it may get the spam flag declined and the others marked helpful if the post wasn't actually spam. Custom flags are generally handled on their own, because each one is different. Again, someone flagging the same thing before someone else isn't going to prevent the later flag from being accepted.

There is the possibility that later flags of the same type could be handled differently, if the earlier flags had already been acted on before the later flag was cast. If someone flagged something as a non-answer, it was deleted, then edited into shape and undeleted, another non-answer flag after that could possibly be declined due to the new state of the answer.

In general, I wouldn't worry about that. If you see something that should be flagged, do so without worrying that someone got there before you.